# how to set a relative box size in toga python

Tags: python, units-of-measurement, beeware

I'm making an app with Beeware and toga using python and I need a box to be half size of its parent.

Does toga have relative size units like CSS? How do I use them?

I thought to use the parent box size as a reference but the Box object has no size-related attributes (at least not documented).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add two children with equal [`flex`](https://toga.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/style/pack.html#flex) values, then they will each be half the size of the parent:

```py
parent = Box(style=Pack(direction="column"))
child1 = Box(style=Pack(flex=1))
child2 = Box(style=Pack(flex=1))
parent.add(child1, child2)
```